# sed unterminated 's' command modify line of file

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I'm trying to modify a groups.tsv file (I'm on repl.it so path to file is fine).
Each line in the file looks like this:

> groupname \t amountofpeople \t lastadded

and I'm trying to count the occurences of both `groupname($nomgrp)` and a `login($login)`, and change `lastadded` to login.

```
varcol2=$(grep "$nomgrp" groups | cut "-d " -f2- | awk -F"\t" '{print $2}' )
((varcol21=varcol2+1));
varcol3=$(awk -F"\t"  '{print $3}' groups)
sed  -i "s|${nomgrp}\t${varcol2}\t$varcol3|${nomgrp}\t${varcol21}\t${login}|" groups
```

However, I'm getting the error message:

> sed : -e expression #1, char 27: unterminated 's' command

The groups file has lines such as `" sudo  2  user1"` (delimited with a tab): a user inputs `"user"` which is stored in `$login`, then `"sudo"` which is stored in `$nomgrp`.

What am I doing wrong?

Sorry if this has been answered/super easy to fix, I'm quite the newbie here...

Comment: Probably one of the variables contains a `|` char. Try another delimiter.

Comment: tried with _ ; / and \ . none of them works

Comment: @aveillon, If you could let us know in your question about sample of input and sample of expected output, it will help us more to help you here. Kindly do edit your question and let us know then.

Comment: Edited my question with inputs, hope this helps, feel free to ask for more if you need to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you are trying to do correctly and if you have GNU awk, you could do

```
gawk -i inplace -F '\t' -v group="$nomgrp" -v login="$login" -v OFS='\t' '$1 == group { $2 = $2 + 1; $3 = login; } { print }' groups.tsv
```

Example:

```
$ cat groups.tsv
wheel   1000    2019-12-10
staff   1234    2019-12-11
users   9001    2019-12-12
$ gawk -i inplace -F '\t' -v group=wheel -v login=2019-12-12 -v OFS='\t' '$1 == group { $2 = $2 + 1; $3 = login; } 1' groups.tsv 
$ cat groups.tsv 
wheel   1001    2019-12-12
staff   1234    2019-12-11
users   9001    2019-12-12
```

This works as follows:

- `-i inplace` is a GNU awk extension that allows you to change a file in place,
- `-F '\t'` sets the input field separator to a tab so that the input is interpreted as TSV and fields with spaces in them are not split apart,
- `-v variable=name` sets an awk variable for use in awk's code,
- specifically, `-v OFS='\t'` sets the output field separator variable to a tab, so that the output is again a TSV

So we set variables `group`, `login` to your shell variables and ensure that awk outputs a TSV. The code then works as follows:

```
$1 == group {     # If the first field in a line is equal to the group variable
  $2 = $2 + 1;    # add 1 to the second field
  $3 = login;     # and overwrite the third with the login variable
}
{                 # in all lines:
  print           # print
}
```

`{ print }` could also be abbreviated as `1`, I'm sure people someone will point out, but I find this way easier to explain.

If you do not have GNU awk, you could achieve the same with a temporary file, e.g.

```
awk -F '\t' -v group="$nomgrp" -v login="$login" -v OFS='\t' '$1 == group { $2 = $2 + 1; $3 = login; } { print }' groups.tsv  > groups.tsv.new
mv groups.tsv.new groups.tsv
```